# How to reboot android device?

Tags: android

I am facing a problem.
I just want to reboot the device just after the installation package has installed on the device. How can i do this?
Is there any way to do this?

please help me.

BR,
gsmaker

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by rebooting the device?

Comment: I'll echo the previous comment, and ask why in the world you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. I don't know if it's possible, but if you did this to my phone without asking and providing a way to cancel, I would instantly uninstall your app.

In my opinion, from a user friendliness perspective the best way to do this is to simply ask them to restart their device at a time convenient to them before using your app

Comment: Basically there should be some user activity like When the installation is completed there will be a message "Would you like to reboot now" "OK" Later". So is it possible or not??

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.  Your application code cannot run directly after installation.

It will only run if the user selects your launcher item, or reboots the device (and you have a boot completion handler).