# Runtime.exec() : Reboot in Android?

Tags: java, android, runtime, root, reboot

I'm looking for a solution which can be used to reboot a rooted device. I jknow that rebooting a device is very poor design for the user, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030037/how-to-reboot-android-device), and it's not really for an application. The main purpose is to reboot the phone during my tests (I work on a video chat application, and sometimes I need to reboot when everything goes south)

I observed that rebooting a phone is far far quicker using reboot in a terminal (`adb shell` or ConnectBot for instance) than going through the usual of rebooting with the [ACTION_REBOOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT), that I can't use anyway.

For the moment, I'm able to get the superuser privileges, with

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

But I can't do the actual reboot. I try on a G1 (HTC) and on a Galaxy S (Samsung) without any success. I located the reboot executable in `/system/bin/reboot`

Here are some of my attempts :

```
Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/reboot");
Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su reboot");
```

I read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) about the pitfalls of Runtime.exec(), but I think I'm not in this case.

As using ConnectBot enable me to do such an action, I'm pretty sure it's possible. Please don't tell me to go and have a look to the [ConnectBot code](https://github.com/kruton/connectbot/), it's a big and complicated project :)

Can you help me with this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: I already answered this a couple of months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580254/android-2-2-reboot-device-programmatically/4772796#4772796 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456467/why-does-my-app-throw-an-android-permission-reboot-securityexception/4772820#4772820

Comment: Following this question, I made a small app that I open sourced: https://github.com/rbochet/Fast-Forward-Reboot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

reboot works fine in android.  you are probably not doing runtime.exec() properly.
you need to handle the

```
    public static void rebootSU() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    StringBuilder sbstdOut = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbstdErr = new StringBuilder();

    String command="/system/bin/reboot";

    try { // Run Script

        proc = runtime.exec("su");
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
                            osw.write(command);
                osw.flush();
        osw.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (osw != null) {
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        if (proc != null)
            proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sbstdOut.append(ReadBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
            .getInputStream())));
    sbstdErr.append(ReadBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
            .getErrorStream())));
    if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the full code, I didn't use Processes in the good way.

Comment: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: @GauravMandlik did you find any thing on this .

Answer (score 36):

Finally after weeks of searching:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

Comment: Thanks, i like this compact one !

Comment: For some reason I had to use: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot now"}); instead, but it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is not working in my samsung device, do i need to give any permission ?

Comment: @DavidShellabarger: It's because `su` might be under `/system/xbin/` instead of `/system/bin/`. The location depends on how you got `su` or how you rooted your device.

Comment: xbin worked thanks! Also shouldn't an unqualified "su" call work fine as well since the path should be already set? I was using 'su' fine from terminal emulator without a fully qualified path.

Comment: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: The device in question needs to be rooted.

Answer (score 1):

I find I can not do a reboot programatically.

In addition, I can open a terminal window on my android phone using Terminal Emulator app,
type su
get the # prompt for root access
and then type "#reboot" 
and I get the response "not permitted!"

Any suggestions?

OK, nevermind, I figured it out.
On HTC phones the reboot command will not work even with SU root access.
Need to invoke BUSYBOX to perform the reboot command.

Comment: If anyone is stuck with the same issue on HTC phones, there is an easier way to bypass that "not permitted!" message, without having to install Busybox : instead of invoking the "reboot" command, just write a "b" into /proc/sysrq-trigger by calling "**echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger**"

Answer (score 1):

This code works on Samsung Galaxy S2, S4, Sony Xperia S (LTi 26)

```
public static void rebootDevice()
{
    try 
    {           
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("reboot \n");
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace;}
}
```

Comment: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle i found working solution.

**If your system is used serial port then execute below command,**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

**if use normal port then excure below command**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

difference is only **`/bin`** and **`/xbin`**

> so can code like if first command throw exception then execute second.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot now"}); seems to work for both cases

Comment: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied