# Code to change Android's IP address/InetAddress?

Tags: android, networking, ip

Does anyone know the code to change an android phone's eth0 IP address (InetAddress)?

(I know that from the command line I can do `ifconfig eth0 new_ip_addr`. But I'm asking about something that I can put into the source code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a class called NetworkInterface but it lets you to retrieve the iface's data. I would recommend using `Runtime.exec("ifconfig".... NetworkInterface -> getDisplayName() and so on )`  Here is some insight on how to write `Runtime.exec()`  in the android's environment -- [Runtime.exec() : Reboot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484535/runtime-exec-reboot-in-android)