# Send Reboot Command to phone via Android Code

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a receiver which listens for shutdown intent.

The moment it receives that, i want the phone to restart instead of shutting down.

I have a rooted phone. Is it possible to send Linux commands like "su " & "reboot" when shutdown signal is received.

Comment: Got the answer here . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484535/runtime-exec-reboot-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/system/bin/reboot" });
Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with one of my Android application. However I use [Root Tools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/) to issue the command. Here is the snippet:

```
getShell(true).add(new CommandCapture(1, "reboot"));
```

I chose to use Root Tools as it will handle all actions related to su. The full class can be found at my [github](https://github.com/rashidi/android-fugumod-kernel-updater-for-galaxy-nexus/blob/master/src/my/zin/rashidi/android/fugumod/updater/FlashActivity.java).